# Java: IDE working well with Maven War overlays

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, war, overlays

We have a Java EE 6 web application which is fully mavenized, and we use the Maven "war overlay" facility to add customer specific files, and which currently runs in Glassfish 3.1.

We have traditionally used Eclipse for development, but I have found that the combination of Maven processing and War deployments may not be optimal in terms of deployment times, and that the mavenization allows us to use any IDE with good Maven support.

Therefore is Eclipse the best bet for our particular scenario (maven war overlays -> glassfish, and debugging it) or is e.g. Netbeans or IntelliJ better?

Please, back opinions with actual experiences, thanks.

---

EDIT:  Some inital experiments with Netbeans 7.2 bundled with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.1 strongly hints that Netbeans work much faster in this scenario.

Comment: Downvoter - care to mention why?  I'd love to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly Netbeans does have some nice features for Java EE Development and can be downloaded pre-packaged with glassfish, making life a bit easier.

BUT frankly as far as I am concerned it comes down to witch IDE you are most comfortable with. As any advantage you may gain from slighly better support, will be wiped out completly by your (teams) not being familiar enough with the new IDE's features and tools.

I guess what you really ought to considering is something like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/), witch plugs directly into the JVM, allowing real hot deployment. And has been developed specifically for faster Development by reducing the time spend on rebuiling and republishing entire projects for even the smallest of changes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  Training costs are, however, not an issue.  Would you happen to have any experiences actually relevant to my question?

Comment: Well it is essentially answering your question - there are no real benefits. Years of experience in working with Eclipse can't be offset by ~5 days worth of training. You will not find any siginficant advantages justifying the change of IDE's

Comment: In that case I do not think you have any experience with the exact scenario I am talking about.   Eclipse essentially cannot hot-deploy overlaid wars.  Shaving of 20-30 seconds of each redeployment in the IDE is what _I_ would call a significant advantage.

Comment: Hot deployment in those senarios has less todo with the IDE - but much rather with the framework. You don't really have to look for a different IDE but much rather something like JRebel http://zeroturnaround.com/

Comment: You _really_ do not have any experience with the _actual_ low level problem here?  The important part is whether the maven plugin can emulate the overlay behavior in a way which works well with glassfish hot deploy - most likely an exploded war - instead of just packing up a finished WAR.  I will repeat the question from earlier - do you have any experiences actually relevant to my question?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure what you are driving at, Maven and its plugins run independent of the IDE, so it doesn't care wether it get triggered by Eclipse, Netbeans or command line. So there is nothing to be gained at that end.

Comment: In that case let me enlighten you - the m2e plugin for Eclipse reimplements Maven functionality _inside_ Eclipse and provides for many, many things, including importing Maven projects inside Eclipse.  It is a very useful complement to the command line build.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, if you are convinced of the benefits of eclipse and do, then why are you asking us? Share with us your knowledge. In your question are the pros and cons that you have already found yourself missing. Questions that share facts already found themselves, have a higher quality!

Comment: @moskito-x I do not understand your comment.  _Maven_ solve an essential problem for us with _overlays_ which I find extremely useful.  We deploy to Glassfish as it was the only Java EE 6 Web Container available when this project was being done. I still, however, like to work in an IDE for all the usual reasons to do so, but the _Eclipse_ support for the "Maven Overlay" -> "Glassfish" is not satisfying.  Hence I look for better alternatives and asked for help doing so, to avoid doing all the work for my self.  The edit to the question _before_ your comment hopefully show I share my findings.

Comment: I miss that in your Question : `the m2e plugin for Eclipse reimplements Maven functionality inside Eclipse and provides for many, many things, including importing Maven projects inside Eclipse. It is a very useful complement to the command line build.`

Comment: @moskito-x I still do not understand your comment.  m2e is essential for working with Maven projects in Eclipse and is irrelevant for working with Maven projects in other IDE's.

Answer (score 0):

All the mentioned IDEs have more or less similar features in regards to maven support and hardly any of then could help you in this particular scenario. You could rather try avoiding maven overlays in development process as it adds time to the build phase. As suggested earlier, you could also benefit of JRebel for faster turnarounds. With that you will not have to run **mvn clean install** and save plenty of your valuable time.

Comment: For instance if one IDE deploys normal wars and the other one deploys exploded wars the latter might be substantially faster.  This is usually very hard to test without actually trying.   I still do not understand why JRebel would help in a web container setting?

Comment: True. If you can deploy in exploded mode - that's awesome. It is just a nasty habit of maven users that I've noticed - running mvn clean install before every deployment. JRebel doesn't help if you already run in exploded mode (since you don't run the full build) but it helps avoiding the restarts - it updates your app at runtime. As for overlays - I think nothing helps, just have to avoid them.

Comment: I do not think JRebel can help Glassfish - a great deal of effort has been done to make redeployment of exploded wars as fast as possible.  You did not happen to actually _try_ doing it?

Comment: Exploded deployment is a part of all the picture. As one of developers of JRebel I obviously tried doing it.

Comment: Your affiliation with a commercial product you happen to recommend, was not clear to me from your answer.   Overlays is part of a solution solving a strict internal business requirement and I'd rather not alter that unless needed.  Do you have additional material on how to use JRebel well when working with an IDE and deploying to Glassfish?

Comment: Check out Lab #10 at this page. http://www.javapassion.com/rebels/ This is pretty much a tutorial. However, we now have a new plugin for NetBeans and the tutorial isn't updated. The new content/tutorials/docs will be up on the main web site soon.